# How can I set the root of one of my domains to mirror a certain page on another of my domains?

Tags: domain, mirroring, mask, mirror-site

**I want one of my domains (freelawofattractioncourse.com) to point to a page on another site of mine (https://dr.katievb.com/freecourse) without causing the URL to change in the visitor's address bar.**

In other words, when a user browses to freelawofattractioncourse.com, freelawofattractioncourse.com should remain visible in the address bar, but the screen should show content from https://dr.katievb.com/freecourse (without the visitor even knowing that katievb.com exists).

My WordPress site is hosted on a Cloudways server.  I'm also using CloudFlare, and I have a "Forwarding" Page Rule set up so that freelawofattractioncourse.com gets bounced to https://dr.katievb.com/freecourse (but that's not quite what I want because it visibly changes the URL in the address bar of the browser).

**Is there a setting in CloudFlare (or some other service) that will allow me to achieve my domain masking goal?**

P.S. I don't want to use iframes.

Also, I think that editing htaccess in the following way would achieve my goal:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} freelawofattractioncourse.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://katievb.com/freecourse [P]
```

But http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p says "mod_proxy must be enabled", and Cloudways (my server provider) won't allow that (and will not let me edit Apache virtual hosts).

Comment: Your solution would appear to be "find another webhost, then".

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: @womble Now that I've edited my question, it's more clearly unique (unrelated to that other question), right?  Would it be possible to have the "marked as duplicate" reversed / undone?

Answer (score 0):

Although not a recommended solution, you can fake it using iframes to load the other site's content directly into yours with HTML.

Note that this is ***not*** HTML5 compliant, but it should work with most browsers anyway.

create a index.html in your root www folder containing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Free Law Of Attraction Course by Dr. Katie VanBuskirk</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="http://katievb.com/freecourse" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Then create a default.css file in the same folder containing

```
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

This will work in most browsers, and it will not show the other site's address.

Comment: Then you should read up on AJAX or jQuery, and how they deliverer dynamic content. That should do the trick for you.